# basic unix ./ syntax

Tags: c++, macos, unix, terminal, g++

I'm compiling c++ programs from the OS X Terminal:

```
> g++ a.cpp
```

I then the run the program from the terminal:

```
> ./a.out
```

**What does the `./` syntax mean? Is this somehow related to `./run`**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.` means "the current directory", so `./a.out` means "the file named `a.out` in the current directory". If you were to type simply `a.out`, without the `./`, then the system would look through the directories on the path (`$PATH`) to find the program, instead of looking in the current directory.

Comment: You *could* have `.` in your `$PATH`, but that's considered a bad idea. It's especially dangerous to put `.` at the front of your `$PATH`. Consider: `cd /home/badguy ; ls` -- but `badguy` has a script in his home directory named `ls` that executes `rm -rf $HOME`.

Answer (score 2):

dot-slash is just a relative path; it's telling the shell to run the program from the "dot" directory, that is, the current working directory. it only works if the program has the execute bit set (chmod +x a.out; the compiler will ordinarily handle this for you).

Comment: to add another example: `ls ./` lists current directory contents, as opposed to `ls ../` which lists parent directory contents.

Answer (score 1):

In all systems, when you type a command, the system needs to know where the command is.  The places it should look for the program are listed in an environment variable named `PATH`. 
Windows searches the directory you are in as well as the `PATH` (I believe before, but I haven't used Windows in quite some time), and if it finds an executable with the proper name in the current directory, it executes it. Windows considers that a "feature," the rest of the computer community sees it as a "security flaw." Therefore, Unix-like environments  do not search the current directory unless it is put in the path explicitly.  You can run something not in the `PATH` by giving an explicit path to it.  In Unix, 
 `.` is the current directory, so `./a.out` tells the system to execute the program `a.out` found in the current directory.