# What is ./ during executing on terminal

Tags: linux, shell, unix, posix

After successfully building the .cpp extension file, there is a need to execute the a.out file using ./a.out command.
What does ./ represent? Is it just a way to execute it on the terminal? Is there a further explanation to what it represents?

Comment: The directory `.` is the current directory, so `./a.out` is the file `a.out` in the current directory. And FYI, the directory `..` is the parent directory. Also, this has *nothing* to do with C++ or programming in general, and should really have been asked on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658364/basic-unix-syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to c++. Its for unix like operating systems.
The ./ says

> look in the current directory for my script rather than looking at all
>   the directories specified in `$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

`.` is the current directory (like `..` is the parent of the current directory) so `./a.out` means "run the `a.out` program from the current directory".

It's for people that don't have `.` in their path. That's a good idea if you share your box or are overly paranoid but, for a home box, it's probably easier just to *add* `.` to the end of the path so you don't have to use the long version.

Comment: There are other problems with adding `.` to your `PATH`; if I type `foo`, I might get "strange" errors if a file or directory named `foo` happens to exist (ie. "Permission denied", instead of "Command not found") ...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, can't say that's ever happened to me, maybe I'm just smarrter than the average bear :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `ls -al`, it lists current directory's files and folders, you will notice that it shows a `.` as an entry.

This corresponds to a reference to the current directory.

To we are telling the shell to execute `a.out` file that is relative to the current directory when we say `./a.out`

Answer (score 1):

When you type a command in a Linux shell, to decide what to do, the shell first looks if there is a `/` in it. If there is not, it looks for:

1. An internal shell command.
2. An executable file in some of the directories listed in the `$PATH` environment variable.

If there is a `/` in the name, then it looks for a file with that name, always.

And the `.`, as you probably know, is the current directory.

So `./` does several things:

1. It prevents the shell to interpret the command as a shell built-in.
2. It prevents the shell to look for the program in the `$PATH`.
3. It makes the shell to look for the program in the current directory only.